# Using an indicator function to estimate a smoothed effect when dummy variable is TRUE

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I have often used indicator functions in my linear regression modelling to allow for the estimation of a coefficient **only** when a secondary covariate is TRUE. This is always in cases where it does not make biological sense to consider the effect when the covariate is FALSE.

I recently wanted to achieve something similar within a gam framework, but the syntax I would normally use does not extend to gam- or to smoothers specifically. Put differently, is it possible to fit a model so that a smoother is only estimated when a dummy variable == TRUE.

As an example, imagine that I had data relating to the behaviour of individual animals throughout the day and night, either active(1) or inactive(0).

One could hypothesize:

1. That individuals show a circadian rhythm in their activity pattern, and tend to be less active at night.
2. That the amount of moonlight affects the probability of being active at night.

The challenge is then how to model (2) given that it only makes sense to estimate the moon effect for sampling points during the night.

If I assume that the relationship between moonlight and activity is linear, then there are no issues:

```
m1 <- gam(activity ~ s(hourofday,bs = "cr", k = 10) +                 # circadian pattern (assumed identical for all individuals)
                     I(moonfraction*isnight) +                        # moon effect toggled at night(1)
                     s(id, bs = "re"),                                 # individual random effect
                     data = df, 
                     family = "binomial")
```

Here, *isnight* is a dummy variable (0/1), such that the moon fraction effect represents the effect of moonlight on activity *given that it is night time*.

But how would one extend this so that the moon fraction is able to have a [non-linear] smoothed effect?

Any thoughts on how one could achieve this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your current model is written

```
m1 <- gam(activity ~ s(hourofday,bs = "cr", k = 10) +                 # circadian pattern (assumed identical for all individuals)
                     I(moonfraction*isnight) +                        # moon effect toggled at night(1)
                     s(id, bs = "re"),                                 # individual random effect
                     data = df, 
                     family = "binomial")
```

However you want a smooth for moonfraction. There are two options which are straightforward to implement in mgcv, but you will have to decide which is best for your situation.

The first gives the levels different degrees of smoothness, assuming `isnight` is a factor

```
m1 <- gam(activity ~ isnight + s(hourofday,bs = "cr", k = 10) +                 
                     s(moonfraction, by = isnight) +                        
                     s(id, bs = "re"),                                                    data = df, 
                     family = "binomial")
```

Alternatively, you can consider the `fs` basis, which assumes the levels have the same smoothness.